# C Grade engine oil in petrol / gas engine

Tags: oil

I recently bought some Castrol Magnatec oil that is rated C-3, instead of A.

The car requires API SG or higher. Looking at the Castrol site, I can use the C-3 oil as it is rated SN, even though C rated oils are for diesel engines.

Will this cause any issues? Should I return the oil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the C-3 you are talking about is an ACEA rating. The two major rating agencies for oils are the [American Petrolium Institute](http://www.api.org/) (API) and [The European Automobile Manufacturers Association](http://www.acea.be/) (ACEA). As was said on [this website](http://www.oilspecifications.org/), these two bodies are trying to bring order to chaos in the world of oil. You are correct that the SN is the most current oil you can get. The problem lies in that I cannot tell you, with the information provided, whether you can use the C3 rated oil. According to [this web page](http://www.oilspecifications.org/acea.php), you'll need to consult your owners manual or service manual. I suppose you could also call the dealership as well. Anyway, here is the listings for all of the A/B/C/E oils under ACEA and what they mean:

> A1/B1 Stable, stay-in-grade oil intended for use at extended drain intervals in gasoline engines and car & light van diesel engines specifically designed to be capable of using low friction low viscosity oils with a high temperature / high shear rate viscosity of 2.6 mPa*s for xW/20 and 2.9 to 3.5 mPa.s for all other viscosity grades. These oils are unsuitable for use in some engines. Consult owner manual or handbook if in doubt.
>
> A3/B3 Stable, stay-in-grade oil intended for use in high performance gasoline engines and car & light van diesel engines and/or for extended drain intervals where specified by the engine manufacturer, and/or for year-round use of low viscosity oils, and/or for severe operating conditions as defined by the engine manufacturer.
>
> A3/B4 Stable, stay-in-grade oil intended for use in high performance gasoline and direct injection diesel engines, but also suitable for applications described under A3/B3.
>
> A5/B5 Stable, stay-in-grade oil intended for use at extended drain intervals in high performance gasoline engines and car & light van diesel engines designed to be capable of using low friction low viscosity oils with a High temperature / High shear rate (HTHS) viscosity of 2.9 to 3.5 mPa.s. These oils are unsuitable for use in some engines. Consult owner manual or handbook if in doubt.
>
> C1 Stable, stay-in-grade oil intended for use as catalyst compatible oil in vehicles with DPF and TWC in high performance car and light van diesel and gasoline engines requiring low friction, low viscosity, low SAPS oils with a minimum HTHS viscosity of 2.9 mPa.s. These oils will increase the DPF and TWC life and maintain the vehicles fuel economy. Warning: these oils have the lowest SAPS limits and are unsuitable for use in some engines. Consult owner manual or handbook if in doubt.
>
> C2 Stable, stay-in-grade oil intended for use as catalyst compatible oil in vehicles with DPF and TWC in high performance car and light van diesel and gasoline engines designed to be capable of using low friction, low viscosity oils with a minimum HTHS viscosity of 2.9mPa.s. These oils will increase the DPF and TWC life and maintain the vehicles fuel economy. Warning: these oils are unsuitable for use in some engines. Consult owner manual or handbook if in doubt.
>
> C3 Stable, stay-in-grade oil intended for use as catalyst compatible oil in vehicles with DPF and TWC in high performance car and light van diesel and gasoline engines, with a minimum HTHS viscosity of 3.5mPa.s. These oils will increase the DPF and TWC life. Warning: these oils are unsuitable for use in some engines. Consult owner manual or handbook if in doubt.
>
> C4 Stable, stay-in-grade oil intended for use as catalyst compatible oil in vehicles with DPF and TWC in high performance car and light van diesel and gasoline engines requiring low SAPS oil with a minimum HTHS viscosity of 3.5mPa.s. These oils will increase the DPF and TWC life. Warning: these oils are unsuitable for use in some engines. Consult owner manual or handbook if in doubt.
>
> E4 Stable, stay-in-grade oil providing excellent control of piston cleanliness, wear, soot handling and lubricant stability. It is recommended for highly rated diesel engines meeting Euro I, Euro II, Euro III, Euro IV and Euro V emission requirements and running under very severe conditions, e.g. significantly extended oil drain intervals according to the manufacturer's recommendations. It is suitable for engines without particulate filters, and for some EGR engines and some engines fitted with SCR NOx reduction systems. However, recommendations may differ between engine manufacturers so Driver Manuals and/or Dealers shall be consulted if in doubt.
>
> E6 Stable, stay-in-grade oil providing excellent control of piston cleanliness, wear, soot handling and lubricant stability. It is recommended for highly rated diesel engines meeting Euro I, Euro II, Euro III, Euro IV and Euro V emission requirements and running under very severe conditions, e.g. significantly extended oil drain intervals according to the manufacturer's recommendations. It is suitable for EGR engines, with or without particulate filters, and for engines fitted with SCR NOx reduction systems. E6 quality is strongly recommended for engines fitted with particulate filters and is designed for use in combination with low sulphur diesel fuel. However, recommendations may differ between engine manufacturers so Driver Manuals and/or Dealers shall be consulted if in doubt.
>
> E7 Stable, stay-in-grade oil providing effective control with respect to piston cleanliness and bore polishing. It further provides excellent wear control, soot handling and lubricant stability. It is recommended for highly rated diesel engines meeting Euro I, Euro II, Euro III, Euro IV and Euro V emission requirements and running under severe conditions, e.g. extended oil drain intervals according to the manufacturer's recommendations. It is suitable for engines without particulate filters, and for most EGR engines and most engines fitted with SCR NOx reduction systems. However, recommendations may differ between engine manufacturers so Driver Manuals and/or Dealers shall be consulted if in doubt.
>
> E9 Stable, stay-in-grade oil providing effective control with respect to piston cleanliness and bore polishing. It further provides excellent wear control, soot handling and lubricant stability. It is recommended for highly rated diesel engines meeting Euro I, Euro II, Euro III, Euro IV and Euro V emission requirements and running under severe conditions, e.g. extended oil drain intervals according to the manufacturer's recommendations. It is suitable for engines with or without particulate filters, and for most EGR engines and for most engines fitted with SCR NOx reduction systems. E9 is strongly recommended for engines fitted with particulate filters and is designed for use in combination with low sulphur diesel fuel. However, recommendations may differ between engine manufacturers so Drivers Manuals and/or Dealers should be consulted if in doubt.

Answer (score 0):

The 'mystery' surrounding engine oils in very many cases is promoted by the after-market, and is normally profit motivated. The main areas for particular consideration are hybrid vehicles, long life servicing, and diesels fitted with DPF's. The vehicles manufacturer test all of their vehicles extensively before marketing them. The recommended oil from your manufacturer is always the optimum choice and will always be the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different engine oil ratings - API and ACEA.

Since your engine requires API SG or higher, and the oil you have is API SN, there should be no issue with using this oil in your gasoline / petrol engine as it is well above the rating for your engine.

You are correct in stating that ACEA A-rated oils are for petrol / gas engines, however so are the ACEA C rated oils. If in doubt, check the API rating which should be available for the oil as virtually all vehicles have this (API) oil rating

Answer (score 0):

after much reserch and am a military vehicle mecanic who runs 2 older peugeot diesels the one to be aware of is C rated oils are very LOW content zddp.. the old school lube booster problem is if ur engin is a bit old as mine are late 90s there metterery isent hard enough to deal with the reduced lubricancy of C rated oils increased wear will result if ure car glove box book dosent say use c rated MODERN oils DONT!!! there are loads of good oils about that are TRADITIONALin formulation  look on e bay -- if its diesel oil you want for an older engin look for a API--CH diesel oil literla search this on e bay oldr formula SHPD oil high in detergent //zddp for the way ur engin was made for

Comment: Welcome to the site. We appreciate you being here and answering. Is there any way you can clean your answer up and use words instead of texting contractions? Also, punctuation and capitalization goes a long way towards readability.